# How can I use DateOnly/TimeOnly query parameters in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding, .net-6.0, typeconverter

As of .NET 6 in ASP.NET API, if you want to get `DateOnly` (or `TimeOnly`) as query parameter, you need to separately specify all it's fields instead of just providing a string ("2021-09-14", or "10:54:53" for `TimeOnly`) like you can for `DateTime`.

I was able to fix that if they are part of the body by adding adding custom JSON converter (`AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(...))`), but it doesn't work for query parameters.

I know that could be fixed with model binder, but I don't want to create a model binder for every model that contains `DateOnly/TimeOnly`. Is there a way to fix this application wide?

**Demo:**

Lets assume you have a folowwing action:

`[HttpGet] public void Foo([FromQuery] DateOnly date, [FromQuery] TimeOnly time, [FromQuery] DateTime dateTime)`

Here's how it would be represented in Swagger:

[image]

I want it represented as three string fields: one for `DateOnly`, one for `TimeOnly` and one for `DateTime` (this one is already present).

PS: It's not a Swagger problem, it's ASP.NET one. If I try to pass `?date=2021-09-14` manually, ASP.NET wouldn't understand it.

Comment: Sorry I can't catch you well, did you mean that you wanna a filter which will check the query parameters in the url, then if there's separate year, month, day, hour, min, sec, then turn them into a datetime?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. TLDR or this is that I want `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` be represented by a single string argument (like `DateTime` currently is). So, there should be three fields on the screenshot above. Updated the question description.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Turns out, there are two solutions:

- Custom [ModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) + [Swagger configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494187/how-to-use-a-custom-model-binder-with-swashbuckle-swagger-and-nswag/49518821#49518821)
- Custom [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter) (Swagger will automatically see it, and update UI accordingly)

I went with `TypeConverter`, and everything worked! Since .Net team [are not planning to add full support for `DateOnly/TimeOnly` in .Net 6](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59118#issuecomment-919811265), I've decided to create a NuGet to do so:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DateOnlyTimeOnly.AspNet ([source code](https://github.com/maxkoshevoi/DateOnlyTimeOnly.AspNet))

After adding it to the project and configuring `Program.cs` as described, Swagger for the action described in the question's description will look like this:

[image]

#### How does it work

First you need to declare type convertor from `string` to `DateOnly` (and one from `string` to `TimeOnly`):

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

namespace DateOnlyTimeOnly.AspNet.Converters;

public class DateOnlyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object? ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string str)
        {
            return DateOnly.Parse(str);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, Type? destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }
    public override object? ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object? value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value is DateOnly date)
        {
            return date.ToString("O");
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

(one for `DateOnly` is the same, but `DateOnly` is replaced with `TimeOnly`)

Than `TypeConverterAttribute` needs to be added on `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly`. It can be done like this:

```cs
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(DateOnly), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(DateOnlyTypeConverter)));
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(TimeOnly), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(TimeOnlyTypeConverter)));
```

To make it a bit cleaner this code can be wrapped in extension method:

```cs
using DateOnlyTimeOnly.AspNet.Converters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class MvcOptionsExtensions
{
    public static MvcOptions UseDateOnlyTimeOnlyStringConverters(this MvcOptions options)
    {
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(DateOnly), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(DateOnlyTypeConverter)));
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(TimeOnly), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(TimeOnlyTypeConverter)));
        return options;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.UseDateOnlyTimeOnlyStringConverters())
```

Comment: You should explain the solution and post the code in the answer itself - the code for the type converter and how you added it to MvcOptions. The code for the DateOnly converter can easily fit in an answer

Comment: BTW, there's a tiny NuGet package doing exactly this - [DateOnlyTimeOnly.AspNet](https://github.com/maxkoshevoi/DateOnlyTimeOnly.AspNet)

Comment: @AlexKlaus Yeah, I know. It's my package, and it's referenced on the third paragraph of the answer. Glad you found it helpful

Comment: For those of you (like me) who had a bit of trouble setting it up from only this info, check out the GitHub page for the project: https://github.com/maxkoshevoi/DateOnlyTimeOnly.AspNet

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use data annotations (see `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`):

```cs
public class QueryForm
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

The swagger/openapi schema would look like:

```json
"QueryForm": {
        "required": [
          "from",
          "to"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "from": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date"
          },
          "to": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
```

Please also follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379235/1143349

Comment: this worked for me, much better than install a nuget package, thanks

Comment: Does this work  starting .NET 6 or other some newer version?

Comment: @maxc137 yes, it works with .NET 6

Comment: I expected to see QueryForm class to have DateOnly properties. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I can confirm `DateOnly` property works as well in .net7 and higher without any additional annotation attributes. `public DateOnly From { get; set; }`